# Finished last VS became last

Tags: word-meaning

> The contest is not supposed to be political but Russia’s entry was booed – nothing to do with its teenage twin contestants and everything to do with its policies on Ukraine and gay rights.
>   There was again disappointment for Britain and Molly Smitten-Downes who came 17th – and especially for France who **finished last**.
>   But the night belonged to Conchita Wurst – whose triumph gives Austria its first Eurovision victory since 1966.

**Finished last**? Does it simply mean **became last winner** ?

Answer (score 2):

Finished last means finished the contest in last place. It does not imply winning. If the contest were a foot race, then finished last means the runner who finished last, crossed the finish line last or after every other runner crossed the line.